# Convert Emacs macro into Elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is there a way to convert an emacs macro into elisp, not like what `M-x insert-kbd-macro` does, the actual activity becoming elisp statements.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I made a package that allows pretty much exactly this at https://github.com/Silex/elmacro

It has some quirks but it works pretty well... for example, the following macro:

```
F3 C-e M-b M-u C-a C-n F4
```

Generates the following elisp:

```lisp
(defun upcase-last-word ()
  "Change me!"
  (interactive)
  (move-end-of-line 1)
  (backward-word 1)
  (upcase-word 1)
  (move-beginning-of-line 1)
  (next-line 1 1))
```

Comment: Thanks! Super fun and easy way to learn more about commands behind the scenes. You can either copy and paste the code and be done or study it to see what is really happening. Really cool for things like `(insert ". ")` versus the commands to "type that for real" which will work with the modes in place. Powerful!

Comment: Glad you like it ;-)

Comment: I just stumbled across this. I like it too, thanks Silex.

Answer (score 23):

Nope, sorry.  There is no trivial way to convert an emacs macro into elisp.

*Update:* There's been some work on Emacs to start down this path.  See [this thread](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.devel/125550) as a starting point.  It's still not possible (June 2010), but there's activity.

The first reason I can think of is dealing with interactive commands and translating keystrokes into proper arguments for functions.

Think of the following sequence:

<kbd>C-x b .em TAB RET</kbd>

This begins the command to switch to a buffer, types three characters, uses TAB completion to complete it and RET to accept.  The equivalent lisp for the end result (in an emacs session where the TAB completion is unique) is:

```
(switch-to-buffer ".emacs")
```

Thinking of completion, there are also interactions with expansion of all types (`dabbrev`, `hippie-expand`, etc.).

A starting point can be <kbd>M-x edit-last-kbd-macro</kbd> which (in my case) shows this:

```
;; Keyboard Macro Editor.  Press C-c C-c to finish; press C-x k RET to cancel.
;; Original keys: C-x b .em <tab> RET

Command: last-kbd-macro
Key: none

Macro:

C-x b       ;; switch-to-buffer
.em         ;; self-insert-command * 3
<tab>       ;; pabbrev-expand-maybe
RET         ;; newline-and-indent
```

Which at least gives you some of the function names.  But you'll see that <kbd>RET</kbd> is labeled as `'newline-and-indent` which is incorrect because at the time of the macro execution, the minibuffer is active and the binding is in fact `'minibuffer-complete-and-exit`.  Similarly, the proper binding for <kbd>TAB</kbd> is `'minibuffer-complete`.