# Emacs keystroke representation confusion

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

I usually define new keybindings in emacs using

```
"C-x (" --> (command kmacro-start-macro)
"C-x )" --> (kmacro-end-macro)
(name-last-kbd-macro)
(insert-kbd-macro)
```

But the code it generates looks different than the code I read and modify in various major / minor modes and other emacs utilities.
I recently came across [this](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/keystroke_rep.html) blog post that   clears up some of my confusion.

Is there an emacs tool that simplifies keystroke representation ?
Ideally one that translates from [ahk keystroke notation](http://xahlee.info/mswin/autohotkey_key_notations.html) to any sane emacs keystroke notation.

Edit: some other reading to clear my confusion:
[keybinding guide](https://www.nongnu.org/emacs-tiny-tools/keybindings/) by  Jari Aalto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sequence you specify does simplify the keystroke representation.  What you're left with is essentially *the* set of keystrokes you typed.

It's already been asked if you can convert an [emacs macro into elisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717569/convert-emacs-macro-into-elisp).

Perhaps you're asking if it could be made more human readable?
If so, then you're in luck.

You can use the `kbd` macro to convert the printed representation of keystrokes into the equivalent vector of keystrokes.

For example, the sequence which results in a `query-replace` of `3` with `tj` looks like: <kbd>M-% 3 RET tj RET !</kbd>

Well, you can manually set that up with:

```
(fset 'my-hand-crafted-kbd-macro (kbd "M-% 3 RET tj RET !"))
```

And this piece of elisp code should generate the above for you if you have named your macro `'my-hand-crafted-kbd-macro`:

```
(defun insert-pretty-kbd-macro (macro-name)
  (interactive (list (intern (completing-read
                              "Insert kbd macro (name): "
                              obarray
                              (lambda (elt)
                                (and (fboundp elt)
                                     (or (stringp (symbol-function elt))
                                         (vectorp (symbol-function elt))
                                         (get elt 'kmacro))))
                              t))))
  (interactive)
  (insert "(fset '")
  (prin1 macro-name (current-buffer))
  (insert "\n   (kbd \"")
  (insert (key-description (symbol-function macro-name)))
  (insert "\"))\n"))
```

To get this to happen automatically when you finish a keyboard macro <kbd>C-x )</kbd>, you can use this advice:

```
(defadvice kmacro-end-macro (after kmacro-end-macro-name-it-and-insert activate)
  "user wants to insert elisp to reproduce the last kbd macro"
  (let ((name (read-string "Name for this kbd macro: ")))
    (insert "(fset '")
    (insert name)
    (insert "\n   (kbd \"")
    (insert (key-description last-kbd-macro))
    (insert "\"))\n")))
```

Comment: Would it be possible to incorporate the first 3 steps of the simple recipe in my question ?

Comment: @Naveen Yes, I can look at that next week.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Trey.
I combined name-last-kbd-macro with your insert-pretty-kbd-macro into  name-and-insert-last-kbd-macro

```
(defun name-and-insert-last-kbd-macro (macro-name)
  (interactive (list (intern (completing-read
                              "Insert kbd macro (name): "
                              obarray
                              t))))
  (interactive)
  (insert "(fset '")
  (prin1 macro-name (current-buffer))
  (insert "\n   (kbd \"")
  (fset symbol last-kbd-macro)
  (insert (key-description (symbol-function symbol)))
  (insert "\"))\n"))
```

now, I can start defining a macro with f8,
end and test / run it with f9
, and name and insert it with f10:

```
(global-set-key [f8] 'kmacro-start-macro)
(global-set-key [f9] 'kmacro-end-and-call-macro)
(global-set-key [f10] 'name-and-insert-last-kbd-macro)
(global-set-key [f12] 'menu-bar-open)  ; originally bound to F10
```

Comment: There's some code I added to my answer to hook this up automatically when you finish a macro.

Answer (score 1):

I made a package that allows pretty much exactly this at https://github.com/Silex/elmacro

It has some quirks but it works pretty well... for example, the following macro:

```
F3 C-e M-b M-u C-a C-n F4
```

Generates the following elisp:

```lisp
(defun upcase-last-word ()
  "Change me!"
  (interactive)
  (move-end-of-line 1)
  (backward-word 1)
  (upcase-word 1)
  (move-beginning-of-line 1)
  (next-line 1 1))
```