# What are your favorite global key bindings in emacs ?

Tags: emacs

Mine are:

```
(global-set-key [f6] 'compile-buffer)
(global-set-key [f7] 'kmacro-start-macro-or-insert-counter)
(global-set-key [f8] 'kmacro-end-and-call-macro)
(global-set-key [f9] 'call-last-kbd-macro)
(global-set-key [f10] 'name-and-insert-last-kbd-macro)
(global-set-key [f12] 'menu-bar-open)  ; originally bound to F10
(global-set-key "\C-cR" 'rename-current-file-or-buffer)
(global-set-key "\C-cD" 'Delete-current-file-or-buffer)
```

The `name-and-insert-last-keyboard-macro` is from [another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121274/emacs-keystroke-representation-confusion).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I happen to have quite a lot of these:

```
;; You know, like Readline.
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-h") 'backward-kill-word)

;; Align your code in a pretty way.
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x \\") 'align-regexp)

;; Perform general cleanup.
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c n") 'cleanup-buffer)

;; Font size
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-+") 'text-scale-increase)
(define-key global-map (kbd "C--") 'text-scale-decrease)

;; Use regex searches by default.
(global-set-key (kbd "C-s") 'isearch-forward-regexp)
(global-set-key (kbd "\C-r") 'isearch-backward-regexp)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-s") 'isearch-forward)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-r") 'isearch-backward)

;; Jump to a definition in the current file. (This is awesome.)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-i") 'ido-imenu)

;; File finding
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x M-f") 'ido-find-file-other-window)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-M-f") 'find-file-in-project)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x f") 'recentf-ido-find-file)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c r") 'bury-buffer)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-`") 'file-cache-minibuffer-complete)

;; Window switching. (C-x o goes to the next window)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x O") (lambda ()
                                (interactive)
                                (other-window -1))) ;; back one
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-o") (lambda ()
                                  (interactive)
                                  (other-window 2))) ;; forward two

;; Indentation help
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x ^") 'join-line)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-\\") 'indent-region-or-buffer)

;; Start proced in a similar manner to dired
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x p") 'proced)

;; Start eshell or switch to it if it's active.
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x m") 'eshell)

;; Start a new eshell even if one is active.
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x M") (lambda () (interactive) (eshell t)))

;; Start a regular shell if you prefer that.
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x M-m") 'shell)

;; If you want to be able to M-x without meta
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-m") 'execute-extended-command)

;; Fetch the contents at a URL, display it raw.
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-h") 'view-url)

;; Help should search more than just commands
(global-set-key (kbd "C-h a") 'apropos)

;; Should be able to eval-and-replace anywhere.
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c e") 'eval-and-replace)

;; Magit rules!
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x g") 'magit-status)

;; This is a little hacky since VC doesn't support git add internally
(eval-after-load 'vc
  (define-key vc-prefix-map "i" '(lambda () (interactive)
                                   (if (not (eq 'Git (vc-backend buffer-file-name)))
                                       (vc-register)
                                     (shell-command (format "git add %s" buffer-file-name))
                                     (message "Staged changes.")))))

;; Activate occur easily inside isearch
(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "C-o")
  (lambda () (interactive)
    (let ((case-fold-search isearch-case-fold-search))
      (occur (if isearch-regexp isearch-string (regexp-quote isearch-string))))))

;; Org
(define-key global-map "\C-cl" 'org-store-link)
(define-key global-map "\C-ca" 'org-agenda)

;; program shortcuts - s stands for windows key(super)
(global-set-key (kbd "s-b") 'browse-url)          ;; Browse (W3M)
(global-set-key (kbd "s-f") 'browse-url-firefox)  ;; Firefox...
(global-set-key (kbd "s-l") 'linum-mode)          ;; show line numbers in buffer
(global-set-key (kbd "s-r") 're-builder)          ;; build regular expressions

;; Super + uppercase letter signifies a buffer/file
(global-set-key (kbd "s-S")                       ;; scratch
                (lambda()(interactive)(switch-to-buffer "*scratch*")))
(global-set-key (kbd "s-E")                       ;; .emacs
                (lambda()(interactive)(find-file "~/emacs/dot-emacs.el")))

;; cycle through buffers
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-tab>") 'bury-buffer)

;; use hippie-expand instead of dabbrev
(global-set-key (kbd "M-/") 'hippie-expand)

;; spell check Bulgarian text
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c B")
                (lambda()(interactive)
                  (ispell-change-dictionary "bulgarian")
                  (flyspell-buffer)))

;; replace buffer-menu with ibuffer
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-b") 'ibuffer)

;; interactive text replacement
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-r") 'iedit-mode)

;; swap windows
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c s") 'swap-windows)

;; duplicate the current line or region
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c d") 'duplicate-current-line-or-region)

;; rename buffer & visited file
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c r") 'rename-file-and-buffer)

;; open an ansi-term buffer
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x t") 'visit-term-buffer)

;; macros
(global-set-key [f10]  'start-kbd-macro)
(global-set-key [f11]  'end-kbd-macro)
(global-set-key [f12]  'call-last-kbd-macro)

(provide 'bindings-config)
```

I actually have an entire Emacs Lisp file dedicated to global keybindings :-)

Comment: You should see my other config ;-)

Comment: +1 for including examples with roll-your-own functions (lambda ...).

Comment: can you show us `;; Jump to a definition in the current file. (This is awesome.)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-i") 'ido-imenu)` ido-imenu ?

Comment: duplicate `C-c r`

Answer (score 7):

Some of my more unusual bindings:

```
(global-set-key [pause] 'emms-pause)
```

First good use for the <kbd>pause</kbd> key in a very long time!

```
(global-set-key [(super \\)] 'find-file-at-point)
```

Just all-around useful.

```
(global-set-key [(super s)] 'shell)
(global-set-key [(meta  p)] 'shell)
```

With the second binding in place, I can quickly type <kbd>M-p M-p RET</kbd> to return to the shell buffer and repeat the last command I typed there.

Then there are the unbindings:

```
(global-unset-key "\C-x\C-n")
```

Never really had a use for `set-goal-column`, and always kept tripping over it.

```
(when window-system (global-unset-key "\C-z"))
```

I hate it when I accidentally type <kbd>C-z</kbd> and iconify my frame.

Now we get a little meta:

```
(defmacro global-set-key* (keys &rest body)
  `(global-set-key ,keys (lambda () (interactive) ,@body)))
```

Just a little keystroke-saving device that lets me write stuff like:

```
(global-set-key* [(shift control n)] (next-line) (scroll-up 1))
(global-set-key* [(shift control p)] (previous-line) (scroll-down 1))
```

Answer (score 5):

Credit for this goes to Steve Yegge in http://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/effective-emacs

```
(global-set-key "\C-w" 'backward-kill-word)
(global-set-key "\C-x\C-k" 'kill-region)
(global-set-key "\C-c\C-k" 'kill-region)
```

It truly is wonderful to have Ctrl-w mean what I'm used to having it mean.

(Also check that article for more)

Answer (score 4):

One of my favorites was something recommended by a coworker that I initially thought I'd hate:

The arrow keys (up/down/left/right) are remapped to scrolling the current window.  To move the cursor, you've still got C-n/p/f/b (or isearch, or tags, or whatever).

Answer (score 4):

```
(bind "C-t" (lookup-key global-map (kbd "C-x")))
```

I never transpose characters so I rebound it to mean C-x when used as a prefix key. I just can't stand reaching all the way for the "x" key on Dvorak.

I'm also using this macro since today:

```
(defmacro bind (key fn)
  `(global-set-key (kbd ,key) ,(if (listp fn) fn `',fn)))
```

Comment: Funny, I think C-x is easier on Dvorak.  :-)

Comment: +1 for the example showing how to create an additional prefix key.

Answer (score 3):

[Breadcrumb](http://breadcrumbemacs.sourceforge.net/):

```
(require 'breadcrumb)
(global-set-key [(control f2)]          'bc-set)
(global-set-key [(f2)]                  'bc-previous)
(global-set-key [(shift f2)]            'bc-next)
(global-set-key [(meta f2)]             'bc-list)
```

Answer (score 2):

`(global-set-key [(control w)] 'kill-this-buffer)`

I was already hitting Ctrl-W out of instinct to close a buffer -- customizing the binding made emacs much easier for me.

Yes, I realize this betrays my origin as a Windows guy. We all make mistakes...

Comment: The inverse problem is rather worse -- I fairly regularly close Windows apps, when I just wanted to cut/kill some text.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't list these in my first answer, but in retrospect I've always found them useful, and I often see questions from people which could be easily solved by use of the `apropos` functions, so I think anything which makes them more visible is a good thing! (I also spotted that `apropos-library` has appeared since I first added these, so writing this answer was useful to me :)

```
;; Make apropos searches also find unbound symbols, and
;; set new key-bindings for various other apropos commands.
(setq apropos-do-all t)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-h a") 'apropos-command)
(define-prefix-command 'Apropos-Prefix nil "Apropos (a,d,f,l,v,C-v)")
(global-set-key (kbd "C-h C-a") 'Apropos-Prefix)
(define-key Apropos-Prefix (kbd "a")   'apropos)
(define-key Apropos-Prefix (kbd "C-a") 'apropos)
(define-key Apropos-Prefix (kbd "d")   'apropos-documentation)
(define-key Apropos-Prefix (kbd "f")   'apropos-command)
(define-key Apropos-Prefix (kbd "l")   'apropos-library)
(define-key Apropos-Prefix (kbd "v")   'apropos-variable)
(define-key Apropos-Prefix (kbd "C-v") 'apropos-value)
```

With these bindings, I type `C-h C-a` whenever I want to search for *something*, followed by the appropriate character according to the specific kind of search I require (with a prompt to help me if I can't remember the possibilities). If I don't know quite what I'm looking for, then a second `C-a` (or plain `a`) at the prompt will run an all-encompassing `apropos`.

If I can't remember what the prompt characters actually mean, typing `C-h` again at the prompt (i.e. `C-h C-a C-h`) will list the bindings.

Answer (score 1):

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c k") '[browse-kill-ring](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BrowseKillRing))
(global-set-key (kbd "M-.") '[etags-select-find-tag](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EtagsSelect))
(global-set-key (kbd "M-s l") '[loccur](http://sourceforge.net/projects/loccur/))
(global-set-key (kbd "M-s /")   'multi-occur-in-matching-buffers)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x M-b") 'bury-buffer)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-b") 'ibuffer)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-/") 'hippie-expand)

;; Toggle show-trailing-whitespace.
`(global-set-key (kbd "C-c M-w") (function (lambda () (interactive) (setq show-trailing-whitespace (not show-trailing-whitespace)))))`

;; Use [framemove](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FrameMove), integrated with windmove.
`(windmove-default-keybindings) ;default modifier is <SHIFT>

(when (require 'framemove nil :noerror)
  (setq framemove-hook-into-windmove t))`

Answer (score 1):

```
;; Generally useful
(global-set-key [(meta ?/)] 'hippie-expand)
(global-set-key [(super ?i)] 'imenu)

;; Emacs Lisp navigation
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c f") 'find-function)
(global-set-key [(super ?l)] 'find-library)

;; Compiling things, navigating to errors
(global-set-key [print] 'recompile)
(global-set-key [(shift print)] 'compile)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-p") 'previous-error)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-n") 'next-error)
(global-set-key (kbd "s-p") 'flymake-goto-prev-error)
(global-set-key (kbd "s-n") 'flymake-goto-next-error)

;; Open URLs in Firefox.  Still not sure which binding I like most...
(global-set-key (kbd "s-<kp-5>") 'browse-url-firefox)
(global-set-key (kbd "s-<kp-begin>") 'browse-url-firefox)
(global-set-key (kbd "s-t") 'browse-url-firefox)

;; EMMS (music player)
(global-set-key [Scroll_Lock] 'emms-pause)
(global-set-key (kbd "<S-Scroll_Lock>") 'emms-next)
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-Scroll_Lock>") 'emms-show)

;; Navigation between and within buffers
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<backspace>") 'bury-buffer)

(defun scroll-down-one-line ()
  "Scroll down one line."
  (interactive)
  (scroll-down 1))

(defun scroll-up-one-line ()
  "Scroll up one line."
  (interactive)
  (scroll-up 1))

(global-set-key [(super up)] 'scroll-down-one-line)
(global-set-key [(super down)] 'scroll-up-one-line)

(global-set-key [(super right)] 'next-buffer)
(global-set-key [(super left)] 'previous-buffer)

(defun other-window-backwards ()
  (interactive)
  (other-window -1))

(global-set-key [(control super down)] 'other-window)
(global-set-key [(control super up)] 'other-window-backwards)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(global-set-key "\M-n"  'next-buffer)
(global-set-key "\M-p"  'previous-buffer)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c w") (quote copy-word))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c l") (quote copy-line))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c p") (quote copy-paragraph))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c s") (quote thing-copy-string-to-mark))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c a") (quote thing-copy-parenthesis-to-mark))

(global-set-key "\C-o"  'other-window)
(global-set-key "\M-o"  'other-window)

(defvar my-keys-minor-mode-map (make-keymap) "my-keys-minor-mode keymap.")
(define-key my-keys-minor-mode-map (kbd "C-,") 'beginning-of-buffer)
(define-key my-keys-minor-mode-map (kbd "C-.") 'end-of-buffer)
(define-minor-mode my-keys-minor-mode
  "A minor mode so that my key settings override annoying major modes."
  t " my-keys" 'my-keys-minor-mode-map)
(my-keys-minor-mode 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;Nice list.  Here's my block.

(global-set-key [f1]   'revert-buffer)
(global-set-key [f2]   'emacs-wiki-find-file) ; moved to xemacsinit
(global-set-key [f3]   'insert-current-time)
(global-set-key [f4]   'replace-regexp)
(global-set-key [f5]   'replace-string)
(global-set-key [f6]   'goto-line)
(global-set-key [f10]  'linum-mode)
(global-set-key [f11]  'my-shell-command-on-region)
(global-set-key [f12]  'eval-region)
(global-set-key [home] 'beginning-of-buffer)
(global-set-key [end]  'end-of-buffer)
(global-set-key "\C-x\C-n" 'other-window)
(global-set-key "\C-x\C-p" 'other-window-backward)
(global-set-key "\C-z" 'scroll-one-line-ahead)
(global-set-key "\C-q" 'scroll-one-line-behind)
(global-set-key "\C-x\C-q" 'quoted-insert)
(global-set-key "\M-," 'point-to-top)
(global-set-key "\M-." 'point-to-bottom)
(global-set-key "\C-x," 'tags-loop-continue)
(global-set-key "\C-x." 'find-tag)
(global-set-key [(control tab)] 'other-window)
(global-set-key [(control shift right)] 'other-window-backward)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mine have a few Windows or Eclipse keybindings:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-tab>") 'helm-mini)
(global-set-key [M-f4]          'kill-emacs) 
(global-set-key (kbd "C-w")     'kill-this-buffer)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-o")     'imenu)
```