# Emacs Lisp Align Keybinding Definition in init file

Tags: regex, emacs, alignment, elisp, key-bindings

I have the following line in my Emacs init file.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x a r") 'align-regexp)
```

Is there any way to hard-code in a particular regex so that I don't have to specify it every time?

Answer (score 3):

You could create your own command with the hard-coded regexp like so:

```
(defun align-specific-regexp (beg end)
  "Call 'align-regexp with the regexp ..."
  (interactive "r")
  (align-regexp beg end "^some.*regexp\\(here\\)?"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just bind that key-sequence to a keyboard-macro:

```
(fset 'my-align-regexp
   [?\M-x ?a ?l ?i ?g ?n ?- ?r ?e ?g ?e ?x ?p return ?f ?o ?o return])

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x a r") 'my-align-regexp)
```

Create a keyboard macro with <kbd>M-x</kbd>`align-regexp`  then enter your regex.

Then insert the macro into your .emacs file with <kbd>M-x</kbd>`insert-kbd-macro` <kbd>return</kbd> <kbd>return</kbd>

Comment: If you go this route, you might want to look at this answer so as to have a more readable version of the macro: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121274/emacs-keystroke-representation-confusion/3121383#3121383