# How to insert a backslash?

Tags: elisp

So I was looking for a way to save Emacs keyboard macros as elisp code - substituting the Emacs key description language that is used by `'insert-kbd-macro` to the actual functions that are mapped to the keys of the macro.

In doing so, I was looking at first retrieving the functions mapped to keys, followed by rendering these functions as strings to be written into the current buffer

```
(symbol-name
    (key-binding "\C-xo"))
```

Would return the string `"other-window"`

However, currently `insert-kbd-macro` saves macros in caret notation (not the nice human-readable one) (eg: `^P` vs `\C-p`) The function `key-binding` seems to only accept the human readable notation.

So in an effort to convert to human readable notation, i looked at the function `key-description`

```
(key-description "\346")
```

returns `"M-f"`

However in order to be accepted by `key-binding` , it requires notation in the form `"\M-f")

an obvious way to do this would be

`(concat "\\" (key-description "\346")`

However emacs only ever returns `"\\"` not `"\"`

To figure out what was going on, I decided to see what the raw byte for the character `"\"` is displayed as....

```
(byte-to-string 92)
```

it returns `'\\'`

I suspect it might be a bug in elisp.

Comment: So you don't actually want to insert a backslash:)? Note that the code for ^M is 13, and you can't obtain it from concating \ and M.

Comment: Actually, I really do want to just insert a backslash! Can you insert a backslash?

Comment: yeah, sure. just type backslash. Btw, `key-binding` reads everything for me.

Comment: @abo-abo So, how would you type backslash? Eg `(concat "\\" " hello")` or `(concat "\" "hello")`? Challenge: put a backslash in a string.

Comment: This command does what it's told to: it concats. Just check with (aref "\\hello" 0), (aref "\\hello" 1). It would be illogical for it to collapse "\\" and "h" into "\h" which is just one char.

Comment: It's one of these things, like iterators of std::vector<bool>. You just have to get it.

Comment: Ah! I see, `(insert "\\hello")` --> `\hello`

Comment: So there is some conceptual distinction between strings are represented in code and how characters are represented in the context of buffers.

Comment: Yes. Anything that you write is first read by the reader and then evaluated as forms. It's like C preprocessor. And they try to make it consistent, so anything that you `prin1`, you can `read`. Almost anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is *Don't insert /'s* - use `read-kbd-macro` to get readable text that also works with `key-description` and `key-binding`.

```
(key-description (read-kbd-macro "M-f"))

(key-binding (read-kbd-macro "M-f"))
```

If you really want to insert a `\`, as you noticed in your comment, you can do so via

```
(insert "\\")
```

But, to save you a lot of angst, you might want to abandon this effort as it's not currently possible to translate keyboard macros into elisp in a general fashion.  See the question ["Convert Emacs macro into Elisp"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717569/convert-emacs-macro-into-elisp).

Answer (score 1):

I added this function to my .emacs :

```
(defun insert-backs ()  
    "insert back-slash"
    (interactive)
    (insert "\\ "))
```

and then:

`(global-set-key (kbd "M-:") 'insert-backs)  ;` call the defined function

means now I combine `'Meta'` and `':'`  to get my `'\'`