# How to convert kbd-macro to real command in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, macros

It seems kbd-macro only records keys I pushed. But I want to record real commands(that is tied with key I pushed) and save these as function.

So my question is something like following.
How to record commands I used as executable format?
How to convert key sequence to command sequence?
How to convert my-kbd-macro to command sequence function?

Example:

<kbd>F3</kbd>(`M-x kmacro-start-macro`)

`C-f`

<kbd>F4</kbd>(`M-x kmacro-end-or-call-macro`)

`M-x name-last-kbd-macro` `my-kbd-macro`

`M-x insert-kbd-macro` `my-kbd-macro`

Output:

```
(fset 'my-kbd-macro
   "\C-f")
```

My desired output is like following:

```
(defun my-kbd-macro ()
  (interactive)
  (forward-char)
)
```

Thanks.

Comment: This question is answered here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717569/convert-emacs-macro-into-elisp)

Comment: Indeed, it would be nice to have an alternative "keyboard macro" facility which records/replays commands rather than keys.  Maybe it's not too hard to do (use a `pre-command-hook` to record `this-command`).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplistic implementation of what you want.
It will work only for simple commands that don't want input, like `forward-char`.
To do any more in a fully automated way seems hard / not feasible. That's why this functionality
isn't in place already, I guess.

I've added these functions to
[my macro package that allows multiple anonymous macros](https://github.com/abo-abo/centimacro)
You can get it from github or from MELPA as `centimacro`.

To use it, just do your <kbd>F3 ... F4</kbd> thing, and
<kbd>M-x</kbd> `last-macro-to-defun` from e.g. `*scratch*`.

```lisp
(defun macro->defun (str)
  "Convert macro representation STR to an Elisp string."
  (let ((i 0)
        (j 1)
        (n (length str))
        forms s f)
    (while (< i n)
      (setq s (substring str i j))
      (setq f (key-binding s))
      (if (keymapp f)
          (incf j)
        (push (list f) forms)
        (setq i j)
        (setq j (1+ i))))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (emacs-lisp-mode)
      (insert
       "(defun foo ()\n  (interactive)")
      (mapc (lambda (f)
              (newline-and-indent)
              (insert (prin1-to-string f)))
            (nreverse forms))
      (insert ")")
      (buffer-string))))

(defun last-macro-to-defun ()
  "Insert last macro as defun at point."
  (interactive)
  (insert (macro->defun last-kbd-macro)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Do bear in mind that when writing a function there are frequently better ways to do things than to exactly mimic the interactive bindings, so while not *necessary*, some refactoring is likely going to be beneficial if you start out with just the commands used when the macro runs.

Anyhow, I can think of a couple of useful tools to assist with working this out manually:

Firstly, if you *edit* a keyboard macro, the macro editor comments each key with the function it is bound to (n.b. for the buffer in which you invoke the editor! -- if you are switching buffers while your macro executes, I would suggest checking the editor for each buffer).

Obviously you can obtain the same information in other ways, but the macro editor gives you the whole list, which could be convenient.

The other helper is `repeat-complex-command` bound to <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>M-:</kbd>, which gives you the resulting elisp form from certain types of interactive function call ("a complex command is one which used the minibuffer"). My favourite example of this is `align-regexp`, as it's a case where the user's interactive arguments are further manipulated, which isn't necessarily obvious. e.g.:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `align-regexp` <kbd>RET</kbd> `=` <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>M-:</kbd> might tell you:

`(align-regexp 1 191 "\\(\\s-*\\)=" 1 1 nil)`